# Сортировка массивов на С++

Tags: c++, массивы

Дана задача
На основе исходных массивов А[n] и B[m] (n и m — рабочие размеры массивов) сформировать массив С, который будет состоять из чисел, которые входят в массив В, но при этом не входят в массив А. Упорядочить массив С по возрастанию, используя метод

«пузырька». Вывести элементы массивов А, В и С на экран.

Массивы А, В и С являются целочисленными. Значения m и n вводятся пользователем с клавиатуры. Значения элементов массивов А и В генерируются при помощи датчика случайных чисел.

Так вот вопрос. Как сделать правильное заполнение массива С, не могу понять почему никак не хочет убирать повторяющиеся члены

Вот код, который есть на данный момент (Без пузырька)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main () {
    int n, m, i, d, b, k, s;
    int A[n], B[m], C[b];
    cout << "1 cikl - ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "2 cikl - ";
    cin >> m;
    srand(time(0));
        for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
            A[i] = -100 + rand()%200;
        for (i = 0; i <= m; i++)
            B[i] = -100 + rand()%200;
    if ( m >= n)
        d = m;
    else
        d = n;
    b=0;
    for (k = 0; k <= d; k++) {
        s = 0;
            for (i = 0; i <=n; i++){
                if ( B[k] == A[i] ) s++;
            }
        if ( s == 0) {
            C[b] = B[k];
            b++;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i <= d; i++) {
        cout << setw(4) << i;
        cout << setw (12) << A[i];
        cout << setw(18) << B[i];
        cout << setw (24) << C[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Если отсортировать исходные массивы - то получение массива `C` становится тривиальным...

Comment: Если это:    int n, m, i, d, b, k, s;    int A[n], B[m], C[b]; компилируется, то какими будут размеры массивов? Неужели вы думаете, что  меняя значения  n,  m  и b, измените размеры массивов?

Comment: А тогда как иначе задавать массив с произвольным размером? 
int A[]?

Comment: массив с произвольным размером - это std::vector

Comment: @Леонид,  сначала, как минимум нужно                        определить значения этих размеров, а потом уже думать как создавать массив с данными размерами.

Answer (score 1):

Удивительно, что ваш код вообще собрался, особенно учитывая замечание @AR Hovsepyan. Пример рабочего кода:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
void BubbleSorting(int arr[], int lenght)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < lenght - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < lenght - 1; c++)
        {
            if (arr[c] > arr[c + 1])
            {
                arr[c] ^= arr[c + 1];
                arr[c + 1] ^= arr[c];
                arr[c] ^= arr[c + 1];
            }
        }
    }
}
void FillArray(int arr[], int lenght)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < lenght; i++)
        arr[i] = -100 + rand() % 200;
}
void ShowArrayContent(int arr[], int lenght)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < lenght; i++)
    {
        std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
int main()
{   
    int firstArrayLenght, secondArrayLenght;
    std::cout << "Enter first array lenght: ";
    std::cin >> firstArrayLenght;
    std::cout << "Enter first array lenght: ";
    std::cin >> secondArrayLenght;
    int *arrFirst = new int[firstArrayLenght];      //Массив А
    int *arrSecond = new int[secondArrayLenght];    //Массив B

    //Заполнение массивов
    srand(time(0));
    FillArray(arrFirst, firstArrayLenght);
    FillArray(arrSecond, secondArrayLenght);    
    //Поиск элементов
    int  index = 0;
    //На случай если всех элементов массива B нет в массиве A, 
    //создаем временный массив с размером массива B
    int *temp = new int[secondArrayLenght]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < secondArrayLenght; i++)
    {
        bool equal = false;
        for(int j = 0; j < firstArrayLenght; j++)
        {
            if (arrSecond[i] == arrFirst[j])
            {
                equal = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!equal)
            temp[index++] = arrSecond[i];       
    }
    //Создание результирующего массива и копирование в него найденных элементов
    int *arrResult = new int[index];
    for (int iter = 0; iter < index; iter++)
    { arrResult[iter] = temp[iter]; }
    //Удаление временного массива
    delete[] temp;
    //Сортировка
    BubbleSorting(arrResult, index);
    std::cout << "First array: " << std::endl;
    ShowArrayContent(arrFirst, firstArrayLenght);
    std::cout << "Second array: " << std::endl;
    ShowArrayContent(arrSecond, secondArrayLenght);
    std::cout << "Result array: " << std::endl;
    ShowArrayContent(arrResult, index);
    //Освобождение памяти
    delete[] arrFirst;
    delete[] arrSecond;
    delete[] arrResult;
    return 0;
}
```